# declaring empty class member in python

Tags: python, variables

i am trying to read a tree structure file in python. 
I created a class to hold the tree objects. One of the members
should hold the parent object. 
Since the parentObject member is of the same type as the class itself,
I need to declare this as an empty variable of type "self".

How do I do that in python?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 11):

> Since the parentObject member is of
>   the same type as the class itself, I
>   need to declare this as an empty
>   variable of type "self".

No, you do not need to declare anything in Python. You just define things.

And self is not a type, but the conventional name for the first parameter of instance methods, which is set by the language to the object of the method.

Here's an example:

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self, label=None):
        self.label = label
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []

    def append(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
        node.parent = self
```

And here's how that could be used:

```
empty_tree = Tree()

simple_tree = Tree()
simple_tree.append(Tree('hello'))
simple_tree.append(Tree('world'))
```

Answer (score 7):

In Python, you don't declare variables as having any type.  You just assign to them.  A single variable can be assigned objects of different types in succession, if you wanted to do so. "self" is not the type but a naming convention used to refer to the current object, like "this" in Java / C++ (except in Python you could call it anything you wanted).

Answer (score 7):

I assume that for the root node, you want such an object.  It's much more Pythonic to say:

```
self.parent = None
```

in your root object, than to create an empty object of type `self.__class__`.  For every other node object in the tree, `self.parent` should refer to the actual parent node.

Remember, in Python you don't have 'variables', you have objects, and there is no need for `self.parent` to be of same type in all the instances of a class.